# Nginx doesn't serve static files

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean

I've just deployed my django website on an Ubunto server. But it doesn't load any static file.

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
```

nginx/sites-available configuration:

```
server {
        server_name 138.197.172.33;

        access_log off;

        location /staticfiles/ {
            root staticfiles;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

Errors:

```
...

[14/May/2018 05:28:28] "GET /static/vendors/underscore/underscore.js 
HTTP/1.1" 404 113
[2018-05-14 05:28:29,252] base: WARNING - Not Found: 
/static/vendors/bootstrap-notify-simple-wrapper/bootstrap-notify- 
simple-wrapper.min.js
[14/May/2018 05:28:29] "GET /static/vendors/bootstrap-notify-simple- 
wrapper/bootstrap-notify-simple-wrapper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 159
[2018-05-14 05:28:29,690] base: WARNING - Not Found: 
/static/js/custom.js
[14/May/2018 05:28:29] "GET /static/js/custom.js HTTP/1.1" 404 93
[2018-05-14 05:28:30,236] base: WARNING - Not Found: 
/static/js/converter.js
[14/May/2018 05:28:30] "GET /static/js/converter.js HTTP/1.1" 404 96
...
```

staticfiles folder includes:

```
admin  ajaximage  css  datatable  dm2bn  fonts  images  js  static  
tinymce  vendors
```

Comment: Did you ran the `python manage.py collectstatic`management command ?

Comment: Yes, I do but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error logs, the link is pointing to `/static/`:

> [14/May/2018 05:28:28] "GET **/static/** vendors/underscore/underscore.js 
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 113

In your configuration, you have set `location` to `/staticfiles`, but your django configuration is saying the URL is `/static`.

So, `location` should be `/static/`, not `/staticfiles/`.

`location` is the URL, and the root is the full path to the `staticfiles` directory.

Comment: Did you also change the root to the full path to your staticfiles folder, and restart nginx?

Comment: yes. i did it. also checked nginx status , everything is ok but it still doesn't serve static files.

Answer (score 0):

you should change `nginx` configuration like

```
location /static/ {
    alias /path/to/staticfiles;
}
```

You should give absolute path in your nginx configuration.

Comment: I've already changed it to:
    location /static/ {
       alias /myproject/staticfiles/;
    }
 
but nothing changed.

Comment: @Resana you should give absolute path ex:  `/home/anji/myproject/staticfiles;`  and each time you change the nginx configuration file you need to restart it with command `sudo service nginx restart`.

Comment: I get the absolute path with pwd command and put it after "alias" and then restart nginx and check its status, but it still doens't load static files. :(

Comment: @Resana add absolute path of a static file in `comment`

Comment: alias /root/parsipool/staticfiles/;
// parsipool is my project folder name

Comment: @Resana what is the generated static path in `http://138.197.172.33` (ex: http://138.197.172.33/static/main.css) ?

Comment: 403 means missing required permissions. Give permissions by changing the owner of directory `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /root/parsipool/staticfiles/`

Comment: `/static/css/main.css` is an example path you should replace it your file path.

Comment: 138.197.172.33:8000/static/css/main.css  is a real path. how about the port 8000? do I need do something for that port?

Comment: `nginx` runs on port `80` so, port not needed.

Comment: execute `ls` in path `/root/parsipool/staticfiles/` and update question with output.

Comment: try to access `138.197.172.33/static/admin/css/base.css` or `138.197.172.33/staticfiles/admin/css/base.css` (in case if you change  static path in settings.py)

Comment: I got "404 Not Found" in both case

Comment: it just override the existing files. I checked http://138.197.172.33/static/admin/css/base.css. It shows "403 Forbidden" even after I change the owner of directory.

Comment: Do you have time to check my server files? I'll send login details to your email.

Comment: @Resana : Just try the same code by removing only the / from the end of static. i.e only by location /static and continue with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your static files are present in path `/static` of your project directory.

Once you deploy your app on the server don't forget to run :

```
python manage.py collectstatic --link
```

`--link` will create a symbolic link to each file into the directory `/staticfiles`.

Nginx config should be :

```
location /static/ {
    alias /path/to/staticfiles;
}
```

Comment: whats new in this answer ?